# Get list of commands run by root user with time

Tags: linux, system-monitoring

How can I get a list of commands run by the particular user with time at which it was run. There are no syslogs being made in the server.

Ps - This is being done to catch someone's mischief on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no logs, then there are no logs.

The *only* place where commands are recorded by default is the shell's history file, `~/.bash_history` or such. Note that it is very easy to remove or bypass in case of "mischief".

Note that Bash does not log timestamps for history items by default. (This feature exists but has to be manually enabled through .bashrc first, by setting HISTTIMEFORMAT.)

All other systems for recording commands (audit, acct, syslog, etc.) would have needed manual activation *before* anything happened, and if you had any of them, your sysadmins would already know about it.